# sql SUM of specific

Tags: sql

I want to get the sum of values of the rows with field_id 31 33 35 37 39 41.

This is the print screen from the table

[image]

---

I use this code to get the sum of all values of one field

```
SELECT  field_id,
SUM(value)
FROM    //table name
WHERE field_id = 23
GROUP BY    field_id
```

How to get the sum of some fields values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the total sum of those fields you could do:

```
SELECT SUM(value)
FROM    table_name
WHERE field_id IN (31,33,35,37,39,41)
```

If you want it grouped by field_id you can do:

```
SELECT  field_id,
       SUM(value)
FROM    table_name
WHERE field_id IN (31,33,35,37,39,41)
GROUP BY    field_id
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just need to specify all the ids you want in your WHERE clause:

```
SELECT field_id, sum(value) 
FROM table 
WHERE field_id IN (31,33,35,37,39,41) 
GROUP field_id
```

Comment: this is good but i needed the one that shows only the value as Filipe Silva replied

thanks for both of you :)